# Bake Stuck at 0% Low Poly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

I'm trying to bake a node setup in Cycles to an image using the "combined" baking option, but the process seems to get hung up at 0%. I can't find anything that's obviously taxing to render. There are some busy noise procedurals, but disabling them doesn't help. I've fiddled with the lighting quite a bit to no avail. The image is a 4096 x 4096 which is bigger than I usually use, but there just doesn't seem to be progress happening at all. How can I fix this? Thanks. The .blend is here:

[image]

My system specs are as follows

Windows 7
8G Ram
3.2 GHz processor
Solid State Drive with 36.5 GB free
Nvidia GeForce GTX 650 graphics card

I use the filmic blender add-on.
I have the problem with both CPU and GPU rendering. It persists if I reload the file, if I restart my computer, and if I append the model to a new .blend file.

Comment: Please consider packing your textures in the .blend and uploading it without zipping it to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), then edit your question to include the link to that upload instead of the dropbox one you have now.

Comment: Moreover, in the time it took to write the above comment, the bake reached 7% for me. Considering the age of my system, I doubt yours is slower, which suggests some other problem. Can you share some info, such as hardware specs and operating system?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Windows 7, 8G Ram, 3.2 GHz processor, Solid State Drive with 36.5 GB free, Nvidia GeForce GTX 650 graphics card. I use the filmic blender add-on. I have the problem with both CPU and GPU rendering. The problem persists if I reload the file, if I restart my computer, and if I append the model to a new .blend file. Also, I have tried letting it run in case the 0% is just a visual glitch, and eventually stops baking and leaves me with the lower quarter of the image done.

By the way, are you the Dwain Dibbley from the Mises.org forums and/or the "random thoughts" blog?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question to include the specs. And no, that isn't me. I only use this nick here and as of very recently on GitHub.

Comment: Your GPU is more recent than mine, though I have more RAM. I can't say whether your hardware is the problem. Would you be able to find out the exact model number of your CPU? Or at least how old it is. A recent 3.2 GHz GPU should be quite a bit faster than one from 2011. Also the speed of the RAM may make a difference. I probably won't be able to resolve this for you, but if you post this info, it may make it easier for someone else to help.

Comment: The computer is 5 years old or so. The SSD is a relatively new 850 EVO. I can't say I know how to find out the speed of my RAM. I have baked other models in a similar fashion with no problems, albeit smaller ones with 2048 x 2048 textures and simpler node setups.

Comment: If you bought your computer fully assembled, I'm guessing it's late 2012 or early 2013. The GTX 650 was released in Sep 2012. Mine is from 2010-2011 with scavenged parts as old as 2007. If it were about the hardware alone, you should be able to bake this, since my system can handle it, albeit slowly (took about 50 minutes). I don't think the GPU is involved in baking, but just to rule it out, have you tried updating the graphics driver? Or baking it to a smaller texture?

Comment: I tried updating the graphics driver. That doesn't solve the problem. I can bake to a smaller texture, and I can bake to a 4096 x 4096 textures on a smaller model, but the 4096 x 4096 on this model doesn't seem to progress even slowly.